# Have there been any successful "airdrops"?

Tags: altcoin, wealth-distribution, auroracoin, airdrop

Starting with Auroracoin, a lot of coins aimed to perform [an "airdrop"](http://auroracoin.org/airdrop.php) and distribute their coins to certain groups of people. I am wondering, have there been any successful airdrops? If so, how did they accomplish this task? I was trying to follow these at some point, but I have never heard of any coin pulling it off.

Comment: I am very interested in this too. Maybe you should have a look at stellar (they doing it bound to facebook users and they are at least somehow successful). I made a proposal for a pure "airdrop"/ basic income currency here: https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/1598/basic-income-circles-reputation-market-based-approach-to-solve-the-identity-problem-sybil-attacs#latest

Comment: @user599464 Well, Facebook authentication is only so reliable. I was also thinking about some basic income currency in regards to this.

Answer (score 2):

I remmeber there was BitcoinTalkCoin - the one with BCC ticker, in fact there were few sharing the same idea). They successfully "airdropped" the coins to BTT users, registered before the coin anouncement. I received some myself :) although it was pennies, you can say that the mission was accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, there were a bunch of people who were able to claim auroracoins through the airdrop using SMS/Facebook based on various forums and social media outlets. In that sense the airdrop was successful. But who knows how many of the airdrops were legitimate. For all we know, most of the airdrop might have gone to the creators of the coins so they could cash out. I haven't seen any evidence against this.

Any airdrop that is targeted towards a local population is going to be difficult and costly to pull off because there is no way to easily verify people's identity. Furthermore, how can you verify that the coin's creators aren't claiming the airdrop to themselves? In my opinion, the creator of these coins are using "airdrops" to build up hype and don't really have any practical way of handling the airdrop. Or worse, they fully intend to claim most of the coins themselves and sell it off before it crashes. In a sense , it's an age old pump and dump scheme applied in the alt coin arena.

Comment: Actually, Auroracoin and other "national crypto currencies" supposedly used national ID systems to verify people's identities.

Comment: From what I read, they did not. It doesn't make any sense how they would do that anyways. How do you verify that whoever is claiming their ID is not an imposter if the ID is publicly available?

Answer (score 0):

Byteball and Stellar did quite well. Byteball is new and the marketcap is already $100M. You can find details here https://wiki.byteball.org/airdrop

Comment: Could you please give us a few more details? How did they select the recipients? What is their niche or makes the coins interesting? How do they compare to other better known cryptocurrencies?

Comment: It uses DAG which is similar to IOTA. It's distributed to all BTC or BYTE holders. I find the distribution completely unique and genius. You can find all the details on their Bitcointalk thread. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1608859.0

Comment: @GeorgioGeorgiev, It would be better to edit your answer to include the requested details.  It's much better than having good answers sitting down in the comments.  You will also have enough space to summarize the bitcointalk thread, which is much better than just linking to it.